# Geometric location

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles, locus

The numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$ are strictly positive. Let the  $ABC$ be a triangle and the mobile point $M$ inside the triangle so 
$$\frac{MA}{a}=\frac{MB}{b}=\frac{MC}{c}.$$ 
What is the geometric location of the point $M$?

I'm sorry, but all my attempts have not materialized.

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ also the lengths of sides $BC,\;CA,\;AB$ of the triangle, or are they just arbitrary positive real numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they are intersect points of two Apollonian circles.

Because we have $\frac{BM}{AM}=\frac{b}{a}$ and $\frac{CM}{AM}=\frac{c}{a}$.

Comment: @medicu You are welcome! One of these points placed inside the triangle, which we need.